# Как пронормировать квадратную матрицу A [5] [5]?

Tags: javascript, матрицы

Как пронормировать квадратную матрицу A [5] [5], разделив все элементы каждой строки на максимальный по модулю элемент матрицы?

Плохо разбираюсь в матрицах, хотелось бы увидеть правильно решение

Comment: Напишите, что вы уже умеете делать из этой задачи. Думаю ответ сюда писать неуместно, так как задача очевидно контрольная, и давать готовое решение просто неуместно, так как в чём тогда ваша работа будет и в чём тогда смысл обучение? Но когда человек уже сам разобрался и большая часть работы сделана, можно помочь понять где ошибка, или что надо поправить, доработать.

Comment: Это не задача из контрольной.Я просто не понимаю, что мне делать.Поэтому хотел увидеть пример нормального, рабочего кода. 
В техникуме на факультете "Электроснабжение" не дают задачи по программированию (как ни странно).

Comment: Ясно. Ну двухмерная матрица это условно такой квадратик с ечейкми, (строк, столбцы) в каждой ячейке значение. В програмирование квадратные матрицы задаются двумерным масивом, вот тут почитать можно как - https://metanit.com/web/javascript/2.5.php , далее надо научиться делать 1. обходить столбцы через цикл и вычислять максимальный элемент 2. обходить циклом столбцы и делить на максимальный элемент.

Comment: Спасибо.Согласен с вами, что теория это важно, но в данном случае намного доходчивей был бы код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, -10, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];
let mx = Math.max; // для сокращения дальнейшей записи назначаем функции Math.max() и Math.min() локальным переменным
let mn = Math.min;
let max = mx(...a.map(e => mx(...e))); // ищем максимальный элемент (а именно, максимальный среди максимальных для каждой строки)
let min = mn(...a.map(e => mn(...e))); // аналогично ищем минимальный элемент
max = -min > max ? min : max; // если минимальный элемент по абсолютной величине больше максимального, будем считать максимальным именно его
let result = a.map(e => e.map(e => e / max)); // делим каждый элемент на найденный максимальный, получаем новую матрицу.
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Podhou добавил комментарии.